# How to exclude CSS element by target?

Tags: css

I have this little piece of CSS -

```
.new-container a:not(.btn):not(.toc-list .cta-green):not(.cta-button-round-green):not(.cta-button-boxed-black) {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#FFB81C,#FFB81C);
    background-position: 0 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 1px .3rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-size .2s;
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

Is there a possible way to exclude ALL the links which have target=_blank in this CSS selector? I tried to `:not(a[target="_blank"])` as well, but it didn't help much.

I am talking about a pure CSS approach, with not jQuery or anything.

Comment: That selector should work. this should also work ` a:not([target="_blank"])  ` See here -> https://jsfiddle.net/9xqvotLb/ Can you the HTML structure ? ( the one that is needed )

Comment: support for `:not(…)` with a list of selectors is improving, you may write `a:not(.btn, .toc-list .cta-green, .cta-button-round-green, .cta-button-boxed-black, [target="_blank"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was quite interested by the question and tried out several solutions, finally leading to the solution provided by Cedric Chollet:

```css
.new-container a:not(.btn, .toc-list .cta-green, .cta-button-round-green, .cta-button-boxed-black, [target="_blank"]) {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#FFB81C,#FFB81C);
    background-position: 0 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 1px .3rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-size .2s;
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

It seems to work nicely on Chrome, Firefox and Edge. IE isn't supported these days so I wouldn't even try to solve it. JSFiddle doesn't seem to run on IE in any case.

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/qchf4wko/2/

I've quickly added a few CSS rules for the `btn` and other classes to see if it works correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS code should do it:

```
.new-container a:not(.btn):not(.toc-list .cta-green):not(.cta-button-round-green):not(.cta-button-boxed-black):not(a[target="_blank"]) {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg,#FFB81C,#FFB81C);
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 1px .3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-size .2s;
  color: inherit !important;
}
```

I've made a working example with your code to see it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/2puan1g5/

Comment: isn't this the exact same code ( selector ) that the OP said it doesn't work for him ?

Comment: @MihaiT It might reveal to him that the selector isn't the issue. The jsfiddle code shows and proofs that it would work. So it might actually be something with his HTML or maybe he/she made a typo. At least I hope it will be helpful to the OP.